# Reading cmd.exe variables inside a MinGW Makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, environment-variables, echo

I am writing installation in a Makefile in which I need to set the PATH env. variable.

In the windows part of it, I found the following:

- `set`: With `set PATH="%PATH%;%CD%"` I can change the `PATH` inside the running environment. There are two problems with this:

  - The environment is a spawned `cmd.exe` by make which gets its variable affected and the effect removed as soon as it closes
  - Even if the previous problem could be solved, still the `cmd.exe` that calls `make` would close one day and the modified `PATH` lost.
- `setx`: A microsoft tool that can permanently change env. variables. According to [microsoft itself](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28WS.10%29.aspx), this is the only command-line option to do this. Using `setx PATH "%PATH%;%CD%" -m` however, turns path into the literal `%PATH%;%CD%` and doesn't replace the variables by their contents!

Note that I am calling `make` from `cmd.exe` not cygwin or other modified windows shells that act more like linux. What I'm saying is that, although I can use `$(PATH)` in my makefile (instead of `%PATH%`), I can't use `pwd` (instead of `%CD%`)

Also note that if in cmd itself I run:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;%CD%" -m
```

it works perfectly. Somehow I need to make `make` execute this command.

Do you have any idea how to fix this, or what workaround do I have?

P.S. Just for the record, `echo "%PATH%;%CD%"` in the Makefile also echoes the literal `"%PATH%;%CD%"` rather than let cmd.exe handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

Create a `.bat` file, put the command there, and invoke it from the Makefile.

I still am interested in a direct fix in the Makefile though.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day i Borland C++ Free Command Line tools included a version of make which played well with the dos/windows command line. Probably still floating around somewhere.

Comment: I'd rather tell the user to change his own effing `PATH` than to switch away from `GNU make`!! Although you gave me an idea. I could put the command in a .bat file and execute that from my make